# SQL Server Browser - Startup Type - Best Practice

Tags: sql, installation, sql-server-2012-express

During the installation of SQL Server Express 2012 on a new machine, I am able to specify the startup type of both the SQL Server Database Engine and the SQL Server Browser.

By default, the SQL Server Database Engine has a Startup Type specified as Automatic.

SQL Server Browser has a default Startup Type of Disabled.

After reading about what function SQL Server Browser serves, it would seem that it is something you would want to have running all the time, since it essentially keeps tabs on the various DB instances, and seems like it would speed up development for example.

What are the pros and cons to setting the Startup Type of the SQL Server Browser to Automatic for example?  Or to get any use, would you need to set it to Manual and then specify it launch at startup?

Thanks.

Comment: Really more of a DBA (rather than **programming**) question -> should be on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move

Comment: I was unaware of dba.stackexhange.com.  I normally program in C#, ASP.NET, desktop software, so on.  This is ultimately being installed on my development machine.  Anyways, this is all for programming work.  If this question needs to be moved, I am OK with that.

Comment: On a dev machine, go ahead and set it to Automatic; for the very reasons that you state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience (after making direct access to SQL Server) `SQL Server Browser` useful if you have `Named instances` and\or nonstandard(standard is 1433)\dynamic TCP ports.

`SQL Server Browser` actually listens on UDP port 1434 (default, should be open in firewall) and returns `Server\Instance name` to `IP address\port`. If you want to connect from remote client to some MyServer\MSSQL2008 or get available in your network `SQL Server Browser` will return list of "Instance name\IP address\Port" to your client.